# A complex SQL Query using group_concat

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called 'stock':

```
    stock_id | prod_id | size | color | shop_id | qty

    1        |   4     |   L  |  Red  |    1    |  3
    2        |   4     |   XL |  Blue |    2    |  1
    3        |   4     |   L  |  Red  |    3    |  2
    4        |   2     |  XXL | White |    1    |  7
    5        |   4     |   L  |  Red  |    4    |  1
```

Some of that..

I have a products table and a shop table.

What I want as result is something like that:

```
    prod_id | prod_name | shop_name |  color_size_qty
       4    |  T-Shirt  |  Shop 1   |    Red,L,(3)
       2    |  T-Shirt  |  Shop 1   |    White,XXL,(7)
       4    |  T-Shirt  |  Shop 2   |    Blue,XL,(1)
```

I dont know if you can understand me. The closest I got was something like

```
prod id | prod_name |        Colors         |     sizes   |
   4    | T-Shirt   |Red,Red,Red,Blue,White | L,L,L,XL,XL
```

Not even close as you can see. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you show us the query you have so far?

Comment: SELECT p.*, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT e.estoque_prod_cor ORDER BY e.estoque_prod_cor) as cores,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT e.estoque_prod_tam ORDER BY e.estoque_prod_tam) as tamanhos

from produtos  p, estoque e

WHERE p.produto_id = e.produtos_produto_id

GROUP BY p.produto_nome

Answer (score 5):

A simple `CONCAT()` may be all you need as opposed to a `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT
    prod_id, prod_name, shop_name,
    CONCAT(color, ',', size, ', (', qty, ')') AS color_size_qty
FROM
    stock
    JOIN products ON stock.prod_id=products.id
    JOIN shops ON stock.shop_id=shops.id
ORDER BY
    prod_name ASC, shop_name ASC
```

Comment: Looks good, although as it is you get `Column 'prod_id' in field list is ambiguous`. Just need to disambiguate it and it works like a charm though - [working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49e1f/2).

Comment: @PauloBarros Sorry, so you can get a result like *what*?

Comment: @DaveRandom thank you man. Very much. I don't mean to bother you too much, but how can I alter your query so I can get a result like that:---------------------------------------------------------------  prod_name | shop_name total_prods_per_shop[] | COlor_size_qty(All in one single line) like: --------------------------------------------- T-shirt | shop1 Total(9) | Black,XL(3) / Red,L(2) / White,S(4)------T-shirt | shop2 Total(3) | Blue,XL(1) / Yellow,L(2) .... and so on. Thank you again!

Comment: @PauloBarros Oh right I see what you mean, [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49e1f/9)?

Comment: @DaveRandom dude! you're awesome! Thank you! Now I see how to use CONCAT and GROUP_CONCAT, is so much clear to me now. Thank you again.

Comment: @DaveRandom sorry to bother you again man, I tried figure it out but  didn't get anywhere. Once I've populated the database, I've noticed that the query is not working right, it's not showing all the products and the sum isnt right to. Take a look at [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7693d/1) please. I didnt change the query,  It should be showing the T-Shirt1, and the amount of products per shop is wrong too, it should be 1 on shop1, 2 on shop2 and 2 on shop3. I've tried to edit the query but got nothing, =/ hope you can help me again man. Thank you.

Comment: @DaveRandom I got it man! I just grouped by prod_name after the shop and it showed me the right result! thank you man!